# the false value not working? for checked/unchecked checkbox

Tags: php

[please click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tLVw.png)PHP CODE: this the code getting the value from database and use it to checked/unchecked checkbox.

```
<?php

$value = FALSE;

foreach ($LOCKPERIOD as $lp)
    if ($lpg->pay_code == $lp->pay_code) {
        if ($lp->generate_payslip == 1) {
            $value = TRUE;
        } else {
            $value = FALSE;
        }
    }
?>  
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked="<?php echo $value; ?>" >
```

Comment: What has this to do with JavaScript? It looks like you're using the boolean as a value of an input, remove/add `checked` attribute according to `$value`, if you need to control the input checking.

Comment: sorry this is php code only not a javascript.

Comment: After i remove the checked attribute the checked on checkbox remove all how about the value= 1?

Comment: What are you trying to output? The string 'true' or 'false'? Because you've assigned a boolean to $value. You could assign the strings 'true' and 'false' instead, or use `value="<?php echo $value?'true':'false';?>"`. I'd also note that whether the checkbox is checked or not is nothing to do with the "value", and you might actually want something more like `<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" <?php echo $value?'checked':'';?>>`

Comment: sir  Daren Chandisingh please click the enter image desription here after the code i posted. thankyou. in this picture you can see my  problem

Comment: and here is my last codes.
<?php
$value = FALSE;

                          foreach($LOCKPERIOD as $lp)
                          if($lpg->pay_code == $lp->pay_code){
                                if($lp->deduct_add_adjustment == 1){
                                    $value = TRUE;
                                }else{
                                  $value = FALSE;
                                }
                          }
                          ?>  
                          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked="<?php echo $value;?>" >

Comment: in your db, is `1` stored as an `int` or as a `string(varchar)` ?

Comment: i stored it as int

Comment: Instead of `checked` type `<?php $value ? echo "checked" : echo ""; ?>` and it should work.

Comment: where did i paste that code sir Jirka? can you edit my codes sir?

Comment: @JirkaPicek Or better: `<?php echo ($value ? "checked" : ""); ?>`.

Comment: @Nemuel It must be placed instead of this piece of your code: `<?php echo $value; ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow following steps, i have edited your code.

```
<?php 
$value = FALSE;
foreach ($LOCKPERIOD as $lp){
if ($lpg->pay_code == $lp->pay_code) {
    if ($lp->generate_payslip == 1) {
        $value = TRUE;
    } else {
        $value = FALSE;
    }
  }
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" <?php echo ($value==TRUE)? 'checked':'';?> >
}
?>
```

It will work. Kindly try it.